# Bad credentials message="org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.UnavailableException: Cannot achieve consistency level LOCAL_ONE

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a 5 node cluster where system_auth key space has SimpleStrategy with RF=1. **nodetool status** confirms that all 5 nodes are Up and normal

Even if one node goes down I am unable to login

```
[Bad credentials] message="org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.UnavailableException: Cannot achieve consistency level LOCAL_ONE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its definitely recommended to have system_auth keyspace RF to be more than 1. Having RF=1 entails only one copy of the storing user credentials and hence any particular node loss would cause loss of a portion of authorization data. Increase it to a minimum of 3.